# Many errors when on trying to deploy on heroku a java - jsf app

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, heroku

I'm know how to deploy a app on Heroku but only in Ruby on Rails, I have been trying A LOT deploying this app: [GitHub](https://github.com/brunoocasali/java-twitter), but I have an issue that I don't know how to solve!

My link: https://twitter-on-java.herokuapp.com/

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class br.edu.unisep.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory
    at br.edu.unisep.hibernate.GenericDAO.list(GenericDAO.java:57)
    at br.edu.unisep.bean.TweetsBean.list(TweetsBean.java:21)
    ... 43 more
```

But if I any change, and run again `mvn package`, and do the push to heroku.. I have another issue:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

So if you can give me a light?

I'm glad your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I had a EXTREME headaches, I found the solution!!!

First my errors switching I don't know how but the issue is, a error when configuring the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<session-factory>
  ...
  <!-- I used postgres instead of postgresql -->
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://foo:5432/bar</property>
  ...
</session-factory>
```

This issue generated erros about `NoClassDefFoundError`, and `hibernate.cfg.xml not found`.

Now I'm happy :D